# Why is there an “are” in the sentence and what is its function?

Tags: american-english

> "We must tell more people how important rainforests **are** so what they will stop doing harm to them."

I can't understand the role of **are** in this sentence, can it be removed?

Comment: Where is that quote from? The "what" should be "that". And I think "doing harm to" sounds a little wonky as well.

Comment: An English exercise set from China, there may be some differences in the details of words used by non-native teachers compared with native English speakers. Although they didn't notice it themselves. So what word is better to use instead of harm? Why do you use that instead of what?  Thanks

Comment: The sentence has an error in it, and a missing comma.  It should be ""We must tell more people how important rainforests are, so that they will stop doing harm to them." So it basically says that rainforests **are** important. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks Billy,I understand your interpretation.

Comment: @BillyKerr I don’t believe that there should be a comma before “so” in this case?

Comment: @AnnabethYeung - yeah it's arguable, but you can use a comma where there is a natural pause in speech if it makes a sentence clearer.  Could say it's optional here, not required.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot leave out 'are'.

Assertive: Rainforests are very important.

Exclamatory: How important rainforests are!

(Assertive: The bird is very beautiful.

Exclamatory: How beautiful the bird is!)

Comment: This is not an exclamatory use: it is an embedded question, which does not invert the subject and verb: _How **did he know**?_ (inverted) vs _I asked him how **he knew**_. (not inverted). Similarly _How important **are rainforests**?_ (inverted) vs _We must tell more people how important **rainforests are**_ (not inverted).

Comment: Thanks Colin,I understand what you mean, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have mentioned in comments, the original sentence is incorrect. This would be correct:

> We must tell more people how important rainforests are so that they will stop doing harm to them.

The verb "tell" takes both an indirect object ("more people") and a direct object. The DO is a nominal clause: "how important rainforests are". Within that clause, "how important" is the predicate adjective, "rainforests" is the subject, and "are" is the simple predicate. Because a nominal clause requires a simple predicate, "are" can not be removed.

Comment: Thank you ，I think your answer is what I most want to know